# How to prevent Github webhook from triggering when a specific user checks in code

Tags: github, jenkins

The webhook configuration is managed by Jenkins.

I have a job that checks in an updated version file to Github after each successful build.

I'd like to prevent a new build from being triggered when checkin is done from Jenkins.

Is there a way to do this?  Is there a way to prevent the webhook from triggering when a given user performs the checkin?

Comment: Some jobs implement different techniques to skip builds. Some use commit messages, ex. `ci-skip`, or you can exclude builds from specific users. Which plugin are you using?